# Complicated Venn-Chart in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, venn-diagrams

so I want to put the following chart in my LaTeX document using tikz. This Venn-Diagram shows all possible combinations of cross sections of 5 sets. I also want not to put ABCDE, but words there (tho that shouldn't be a problem, I guess).

[image]

Currently my code is:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 1.3,
        myellipse/.style={
            draw, ellipse, 
            inner xsep=3.9cm, 
            inner ysep=2cm}]
            
        \coordinate (C1) at (0,1.15);
        \coordinate (C2) at (-0.8,0.5); 
        \coordinate (C3) at (-0.8,-0.2);
        \coordinate (C4) at (0,-0.8);   
        \coordinate (C5) at (1,0);
        
        \node[myellipse, rotate=-75] at (C1) {};
        \node[myellipse, rotate=-10] at (C2) {};
        \node[myellipse, rotate=70] at (C3) {};
        \node[myellipse, rotate=-40] at (C4) {};
        \node[myellipse, rotate=20] at (C5) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

but I just can't get it look right. The parameters have to be rather precise for all the cross sections to be there.
Currently it looks like this:

[image]

The color is not necessary. Can someone please help me?

Comment: Nvm, I got it done c:

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @BigBrotherNii, welcome. // Fine. Do you mind to post yourself an answer to share it with this community? Thank you

Comment: The way I got the proposed chart pretty accurately was mainly through trial and error, actually.

Answer (score 2):

The way I got the proposed chart pretty accurately was mainly through trial and error, actually.

This is how I did it:

```
\usepackage{tikz}    
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, fit, shapes.geometric}
    ...
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 1.3,
                myellipse/.style={
                    draw, ellipse, 
                    inner xsep=3.9cm, 
                    inner ysep=2cm}]
                    
                \coordinate (R1) at (-5.3,-4.5);        
                \coordinate (R2) at (5.3,5.5);
                \draw (R1) rectangle (R2);
                
                %\draw[step=1, opacity=0.3] (R1) grid (R2);
                    
                \coordinate (C1) at (0,1.15);
                \coordinate (C2) at (-0.8,0.5); 
                \coordinate (C3) at (-0.8,-0.2);
                \coordinate (C4) at (0,-0.8);   
                \coordinate (C5) at (1,0);
                
                \node[myellipse, rotate=-75] at (C1) {};
                \node[myellipse, rotate=-10] at (C2) {};
                \node[myellipse, rotate=70] at (C3) {};
                \node[myellipse, rotate=-40] at (C4) {};
                \node[myellipse, rotate=20] at (C5) {};
            \end{tikzpicture}
```